# Rails Tutorial static pages routes test red (5.28)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Doing Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, but stumped on Listing 5.28 (getting RED test instead of GREEN), changing the test to match the new routes.

**ERRORS for all pages (/, /about, /contact, /help):**

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/*", :controller=>"static_pages"}
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
end
```

**tests/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get home" do
    get root_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get help_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get about_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get contact" do
    get contact_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

end
```

**static_pages_controller.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end

end
```

Let me know if you need to see any other code! Have tried adding as: '*' after each get route, but to no avail.

Not sure if it is a ruby/rails version issue, but I am using Rails 4.2.2 and Ruby 2.3.0 on an IDE, but "rails test" (as Hartl instructs to use) won't work (kicks back "test Command not found"). Not sure if that's a hint to a bigger problem or unrelated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Links using these paths (like below) are rendering correctly, it is just failing the tests.

```
<%= link_to "Home",   root_path %>
<%= link_to "Help",   help_path %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb** have problem. I would suggest to replace it with below contents.

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should get home" do
    get root_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get help_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get about_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get contact" do
    get contact_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end
end
```

Change the above file as I have suggested and run `$ rails test` you can see green test. I also suggest you to upgrade your app to rails 5.0.0 as Michael Hartl's have been upgraded his [rails tutorials](https://www.railstutorial.org) to rails 5.0.0 in future you have more things to learn and if you upgrade it, your journey of learning would be more error free and pleasant.

Comment: Versions was the issue! In the earlier chapters, I was in an older edition of the book, which told me to create the sample app using 4.2.2. Then somehow a few chapters later it switched to the latest version of the book for 5.0.0. Not sure how long I got through it without noticing it, but I started the app from scratch (being sure I was on the 5.0.0 edition of Hartl's book). Now everything is working like a charm-- definitely learned a valuable lesson of making sure I'm on the right version... and edition!